# R - selecting data with [a:b, c:d] not working

Tags: r

Got a data set with a bunch of rows (1-285) and columns (x__1-x__70). Trying to select data from rows 12 and 13, starting from column x__5 to x__70.

I can select individual cells `WPP[12,"x__5"]`, full columns `WPP[,x__5]`, full rows `WPP[12,]`, full row ranges `WPP[12:13,]`, but can't do column ranges.

I'd like `WPP[12:13,"X__5":"x__70"]` but I get this:

> "Error in "X__5":"x__70" : NA/NaN argument
>       In addition: Warning messages:
>       1: In check_names_df(j, x) : NAs introduced by coercion
>       2: In check_names_df(j, x) : NAs introduced by coercion"

Comment: WPP[12:13,colnames(WPP) %in% c("X__5","X__70")]

Comment: You need to subset() your DF.

Comment: WPP[12:13,5:70]

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, while converting some of the SAS code in R. Unfortunately R does not have any mechanism, which can be used for this purpose.

Hence, its important that you do it using the available set of tools. In R, you can subset columns by name(you have to give all column names, explicitly), or position index.

Below are the two solutions:

1. `WPP[12:13, paste0("X__", 5:70)]  # explicit column names`
2. `requiredColIndex <- which(names(WPP) %in% paste0("X__", 5:70))`
    `WPP[12:13, requiredColIndex] # using the index of columns`

You can also use subset function, as pointed out in the comments.

```
rowIndex <- 1:nrow(mtcars) %in% 12:15
subset(mtcars, rowIndex, select=wt:gear)
```

But sub-setting rows in subset is a bit tricky, as one can observe in the code above. However you can always use, something like below:

```
subset(mtcars[12:15, ], select=wt:gear)
```

which will give similar result.

However, if you are doing subsetting of rows using data-frame way/method, then it is easier to subset the columns using similar data-frame way/method.